# What is major difference between MAX3232 and MAX3245 wrt UART?

Tags: uart

I am not able to figure out the exact difference.
Please help me in understanding the difference in better ways.

Comment: You'd better post your question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

MAX3232 and MAX3245 both are used for RS232 interfacing .The difference is in the Feature 
 AutoShutdown Plus which MAX3245 has .
To quote from the Data sheet 
" Thesedevices automatically enter a low-power shutdown
mode when the RS-232 cable is disconnected or the
transmitters of the connected peripherals are inactive,
and the UART driving the transmitter inputs is inactive
for more than 30 seconds. They turn on again when
they sense a valid transition at any transmitter or receiver
input. AutoShutdown Plus saves power without
changes to the existing BIOS or operating system"
(http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3224-MAX3245.pdf)
MAX3232 does not have this feature enabled.